# VS Code - Running scala debugger will open in debug console instead of terminal

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code

[image]

I'm trying to debug my Scala program. When launching the debugger, it would normally send output to the terminal. I have no idea why but now it's sending output to the debug console, which means I can't send input back in to the program. Running without the debugger makes it send output to the terminal like normal. I'm sure you'll need more info to help me with this but I don't really know what else to show so bear with me.